# Get current user with spring aop

Tags: spring-aop

I use spring boot 2 and spring security.

With aop, I search to get user who called the method.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.moplogy.controller.*))")
    public void getAllAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){

        System.out.println("method called " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: It looks like your problem is solved because you already accepted an answer. But let me just mention that your pointcut syntax is also wrong. In AspectJ `execution(* com.sita.toplogy.controller.*))` would not even compile, in Spring AOP at least it should make your aspect unusable. The syntax should rather be something like `execution(* com.sita.toplogy.controller..*(..))`, depending on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to add in you method this line

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```